# Real-time plot matplotlib inside Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, tkinter

Let's say I have a function called trajectory that plots the position of a few objects in a 2D plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def trajectory(listOfObjects, time):
   #Stuff happens here
   plt.scatter(x,y)
```

I iterate this function so it plots new points in the same graph, effectively plotting a full trajectory over enough iterations. Something like this:

```
while True:
   time += 1
   trajectory(listOfObjects, time)
   plt.pause(0.001)
```

Now I want this program to run embedded in a Tkinter window. How can I achieve this? I don't know how to run this loop indefinitely while also using tkinter's mainloop()

Comment: Does this help explain how to run animated loops? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32457372/7432